# Which is faster for inserting and fetching, MySQL database or simple csv file

Tags: php, mysql, database, filesystems

A CRM is hitting my server via web hooks at-least 1000 times and I cannot process all the requests at once. 
So I am thinking about saving it (in Mysql or csv file) and then process 1 record at a time.

which method is faster if there are approx 100 000 records and I have to process one record at a time.

Comment: Use mysql it's better and safe.

Answer (score 1):

As you definitely know, `CSV` won't let you create `indexes` for fast searching. Setting indexes to your table columns speeds up the searching to a really great great degree, and you cannot ignore this fact.

If you need all your data from a `single table` (for instance, app config), CSV is faster, otherwise not. Hence, For simple inserting and table-scan (non-index based) searches, CSV is faster. Also, Consider that updating or deleting from a CSV is nontrivial. If you use CSV, you need to be really careful to handle multiple threads / processes correctly, otherwise you'll get bad data or corrupt your file.

Mysql offers a lot of `capabilities` such as SQL queries, transactions, data manipulation or concurrent access here, yet CSV is certainly not for these things. Mysql, as mentioned by Simone Rossaini, is also `safe`. You may not overlook this fact as well.

**SUMMARY**

If you are going for `simple inserting` and `table-scan (non-index based) searches`, `CSV` is definitely faster. Yet, it has many shortcomings when you compare it with the countless capabilities of MySql.

Answer (score 0):

Different methods are available to perform such operation:

1. You can store data in MySQL and write a PHP script which will fetch request from MySQL database and process one by one. That script you can run automatically using crontab or scheduler after specific interval.
2. You can implement custom queues functionality using PHP + MySQL

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need the following:

1) An incoming queue table where all the new rows get inserted without processing. An appropriately configured InnoDB table should be able to handle 1000 INSERTs/second unless you are running on a Raspberry Pi or something similarly underspecified. You should probably have this partitioned so that instead of deleting the records after processing, you can drop partitions instead (ALTER TABLE ... DROP PARTITION is much, much cheaper than a large DELETE operation).

2) A scheduled event that processes the data in the background, possibly in batches, and cleans up the original queue table.